# How to skip the next iteration during a for loop in python?

Tags: python

I have the following code that runs breadth first search (bfs) on a list of graph vertices.

Currently I have code that is running bfs on every item in the list, but I want to make it so that if the next item in the for loop is already in the set of discovered nodes, then the for loop should skip over it, so that bfs does not have to be performed on every vertex.

My main reason for doing this is because I have to read in a very large file, so it causes a memory crash when I perform bfs on every vertex; my code works on small test cases but not on the large file.

I know the continue statement allows you to skip over the current iteration, but I can't figure how to skip the next iteration.

Any help is appreciated; thank you.

```
def count_components(g):
    dictionary = {}
    dict_list = {}
    for i in g.vertices():
      dictionary = breadth_first_search(g,i)
      dictionary_keys = list(dictionary.keys())
      dict_list[i] = dictionary_keys
    for value in dict_list.values():
      for i in range(len(value)):
        value[i] = str(value[i])
    result = {}
    for key, value in dict_list.items():
      dict_list[key].sort(key=str.lower)
      if value not in result.values():
        result[key] = value
    count = len(result)
    return count
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply skip the current iteration if the current item is already in the set of discovered nodes?

Comment: Can you indicate where (which loop) you want this skipping to take place? Maybe add a conditional and then `# HELP - here`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Two options, which you pick is up to you:

1) Start your loop with a guard clause.  This lets you call `continue` and skip that iteration of the loop.

```
>>> values = [0,1,2,1,0]
>>> known = set([2])
>>> for i in values:
...   if i in known:
...     continue
...   print i
...   known.add(i)
...
0
1
```

2) Use a generator in the for statement:

```
>>> values = [0,1,2,1,0]
>>> known = set([2])
>>> for i in (x for x in values if not x in known):
...   print i
...   known.add(i)
...
0
1
```

Which is best is up to you.

Comment: You should use a set for the `known` values for O(1) lookup instead of O(n) (which will be large for big files)

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips good point! Edited.  May as well follow good practice at all times :)

Comment: Thank you for getting me started on the right track! I have a feeling that using sets will clean up and speed up my code much more.